# How do I get the height of an AVL tree?

Tags: avl-tree

This is my AVL tree class:

```
    public class AVLTree1 {

    // Each AVLtree object is (a header of) an AVL-tree.
    // This AVL-tree is represented simply by a reference to its root node (root).
    private Node root;

    public AVLTree1 () {
    // Construct an empty AVL-tree.
        this.root = null;
    }

//    public size () {
//    // Return the size (i.e., number of elements) of this AVL-tree.
//        return sizeOfSubtree(root);
//    }

    public Node search (Comparable target) {
    // Find which if any node of this AVL-tree contains an element equal to target. 
    // Return a link to that node (or null if there is none).
        int direction = 0;  // ... 0 for here, < 0 for left, > 0 for right
        Node curr = this.root;
        for (;;) {
            if (curr == null)
                return null;
            direction = target.compareTo(curr.element);
            if (direction == 0)
                return curr;
            if (direction < 0)
                curr = curr.left;
            else  // direction > 0
                curr = curr.right;
        }
    }

    public void insert (Comparable elem) {
    // Insert the element elem in this AVL-tree.
        Node ins = insertBST(elem);
        if (ins != null)
            rebalance(ins);
    }

    private Node insertBST (Comparable elem) {
    // Insert the element elem in this AVL-tree, treating it as an ordinary
    // binary search tree. Return a link to the newly-inserted leaf node, or null
    // if no node was inserted.
        int direction = 0;  // ... 0 for here, < 0 for left, > 0 for right
        Node parent = null, curr = root;
        for (;;) {
            if (curr == null) {
                Node ins = new Node(elem, parent);
                if (root == null)
                    root = ins;
                else {
                    if (direction < 0)
                        parent.left = ins;
                    else  // direction > 0
                        parent.right = ins;
                }
                return ins;
            }
            direction = elem.compareTo(curr.element);
            if (direction == 0)
                return null;
            parent = curr;
            if (direction < 0)
                curr = curr.left;
            else  // direction > 0
                curr = curr.right;
        }
    }

    private Node deletee = null;  // link to node just deleted
                                  // (accessed only by delete and auxiliary methods)

    public void delete (Comparable elem) {
    // Delete the element elem from this AVL-tree.
        deleteBST(elem);
        if (deletee != null) {
            rebalance(deletee);
            deletee = null;
        }
    }

    private void deleteBST (Comparable elem) {
    // Delete the element elem in this AVL-tree, treating it as an ordinary
    // binary search tree.
        int direction = 0;  // ... 0 for here, < 0 for left, > 0 for right
        Node curr = this.root;
        for (;;) {
            if (curr == null)
                return;
            direction = elem.compareTo(curr.element);
            if (direction == 0) {
                Node modified = deleteTopmost(curr);
                Node parent = curr.parent;
                if (curr == this.root)
                    this.root = modified;
                else if (curr == parent.left)
                    parent.left = modified;
                else  // curr == parent.right
                    parent.right = modified;
                if (modified != null)  modified.parent = parent;
                return;
            }
            if (direction < 0)
                curr = curr.left;
            else  // direction > 0
                curr = curr.right;
        }
    }

    private Node deleteTopmost (Node top) {
    // Delete the topmost element in the subtree whose topmost node is top.
    // Return a link to the modified subtree.
        if (top.left == null) {
            deletee = top;
            return top.right;
        } else if (top.right == null) {
            deletee = top;
            return top.left;
        } else {  // top has both a left child and a right child
            top.element = top.right.getLeftmost();
            top.right = deleteLeftmost(top.right);
            return top;
        }
    }

    private Node deleteLeftmost (Node top) {
    // Delete the leftmost node of the (nonempty) subtree
    // whose topmost node is top.
    // Return a link to the modified subtree.
        Node curr = top;
        while (curr.left != null)
            curr = curr.left;
        deletee = curr;
        if (curr == top)
            return top.right;
        else {
            curr.parent.left = curr.right;
            return top;
        }
    }




    private void rebalance (Node node) {
    // Rebalance this AVL-tree, following insertion or deletion of node.
        Node ancestor = node;
        while (ancestor != root) {
            ancestor = ancestor.parent;
            ancestor.setHeight();
            if (! ancestor.isHeightBalanced()) {
                Node greatAncestor = ancestor.parent;
                Node rotated = rotate(ancestor);
                if (ancestor == root)
                    setRoot(rotated);
                else if (ancestor == greatAncestor.left)
                    greatAncestor.setLeft(rotated); 
                else  // ancestor == greatgrandparent.right
                    greatAncestor.setRight(rotated);
                ancestor = rotated;
            }
        }
    }

    private Node rotate (Node grandparent) {
    // Rotate the node grandparent, the node parent (grandparent's higher child),
    // and the node child (parent's higher child).
    // After an insertion, all three nodes are ancestors of the inserted node.
    // After a deletion, only grandparent is an ancestor of the deleted node.
        Node parent = grandparent.higherChild();
        Node child = parent.higherChild();
        Node a, b, c;
        Node t1, t2, t3, t4;
        if (child == parent.left && parent == grandparent.left) {
            a = child;  b = parent;  c = grandparent;
            t1 = child.left;  t2 = child.right;
            t3 = parent.right;  t4 = grandparent.right;
        } else if (child == parent.right && parent == grandparent.left) {
            a = parent;  b = child;  c = grandparent;
            t1 = parent.left;  t2 = child.left;
            t3 = child.right;  t4 = grandparent.right;
        } else if (child == parent.right && parent == grandparent.right) {
            a = grandparent;  b = parent;  c = child;
            t1 = grandparent.left;  t2 = parent.left;
            t3 = child.left;  t4 = child.right;
        } else {  // child == parent.left && parent == grandparent.right
            a = grandparent;  b = child;  c = parent;
            t1 = grandparent.left;  t2 = child.left;
            t3 = child.right;  t4 = parent.right;
        }
        print();
        System.out.println("... now rebalancing"
                + " a = " + a.element
                + " b = " + b.element
                + " b = " + c.element);
        a.setLeft(t1);  a.setRight(t2);  a.setHeight();
        c.setLeft(t3);  c.setRight(t4);  c.setHeight();
        b.setLeft(a);   b.setRight(c);   b.setHeight();
        return b;
    }

    private void setRoot (Node newRoot) {
    // Make newRoot this AVL-tree's root node.
        this.root = newRoot;
        newRoot.parent = null;
    }

    //////////// Driver ////////////

    public void print () {
    // Print a textual representation of this AVL-tree.
        printSubtree(root, "");
    }

    private static void printSubtree (Node top, String indent) {
    // Print a textual representation of the subtree of this AVL-tree whose
    // topmost node is top, indented by the string of spaces indent.
        if (top == null)
            System.out.println(indent + "o");
        else {
            System.out.println(indent + "o-->");
            String childIndent = indent + "    ";
            printSubtree(top.right, childIndent);
            System.out.println(childIndent + top.element + " (" + top.height + ")"
                    + (top.parent == null ? "" : " parent " + top.parent.element.toString()));
            printSubtree(top.left, childIndent);
        }
    }



    //////////// Inner class ////////////

    public static class Node {

        // Each Node object is an AVL-tree node.
        // This node is represented by its element (element) together with
        // references to its left child (left), its right child (right), and
        // its parent (parent), and its height (height).
        // For every element x stored in the subtree at left:
        //    x.compareTo(element) < 0
        // For every element y stored in the subtree at right:
        //    y.compareTo(element) > 0
        private Comparable element;
        private Node left, right, parent;
        private int height;

        public Node (Comparable elem, Node parent) {
        // Construct an AVL-tree node with element elem and no children.
            this.element = elem;
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
            this.parent = parent;
            this.height = 0;
        }

        private Comparable getLeftmost () {
        // Return the element in the leftmost node of the (nonempty) subtree
        // whose topmost node is this.
            Node curr = this;
            while (curr.left != null)
                curr = curr.left;
            return curr.element;
        }

        private static int sizeOfSubtree (Node top) {
        // Return the size of the subtree whose topmost node is top.
            if (top == null)
                return 0;
            else
                return 1 + sizeOfSubtree(top.left) + sizeOfSubtree(top.right);
        }

        private void setLeft (Node child) {
        // Make child the left child of this node.
            left = child;
            if (child != null)  child.parent = this;
        }

        private void setRight (Node child) {
        // Make child the right child of this node.
            right = child;
            if (child != null)  child.parent = this;
        }

        private void setHeight () {
        // Recompute the height of this node (assuming that the heights of its
        // children are accurate).
            height = Math.max(getHeight(left), getHeight(right)) + 1;
        }

        public static int getHeight (Node node) {
        // Return the height of node.
            return (node == null ? -1 : node.height);
        }

        private Node higherChild () {
        // Return the child of this node with the greater height.
        // If the heights are equal, return either child.
            return (getHeight(left) >= getHeight(right) ? left : right);
        }

        private boolean isHeightBalanced () {
        // Return true if and only if this node is height-balanced, i.e.,
        // the heights of its children differ by at most one.
            int balance = getHeight(left) - getHeight(right);
            return (balance >= -1 && balance <= +1);
        }

    }

}
```

I need a function  to calculate the height of this tree.  How do I get the height of an AVL tree?

Comment: The height of any binary search tree is `max(height of left subtree, height of right subtree) + 1`. It is very simple to design a recursive function that takes advantage of this fact.

Answer (score 0):

To get height of any Binary Tree, you can do in either of following 2 ways:

1. Without add property in node: (in pseudo code)

   ```
   getHeight(Node)

       if node is leafnode then return 1;

       if node has one child, then return getHeight(left/right node)+1

       if node has 2 children, then return max(getHeight(left node), getHeight(right node))+1;
   ```

2 Or, you can add one more property called height to the Node, then the method would look like this:

```
 getHeight(Node)
 
     if node is leafnode then return 1;
     
     if node has one child, get that child's height value+1

     if node has 2 child, get max(left child's height, right child's height)
```

First method recursively calculate the height every time. You do not need to maintain one extra property, but you do run risk of stack overflow if the tree get really big.

For second method, you never need to worry about stack overflow, but you do need to do some extra work when insert and delete from the tree. You need to update height value of each node you have visited during insert/delete process.